# Cumulative count of column based on Month

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, cumsum

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
dict_1 = {"Code" : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
          'Period' : ['2022-04-29','2022-04-29', '2022-04-30', '2022-05-01', '2022-05-01', '2022-05-01']}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(dict_1)
df_1['Period'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1['Period']).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
df_1.head(10)
```

| Code | Period |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2022-04-29 |
| A | 2022-04-29 |
| A | 2022-04-30 |
| A | 2022-05-01 |
| A | 2022-05-01 |
| A | 2022-05-01 |

I have to create a new column, i.e., if the month ends then `Count` should start from 1.

Below is the code that I have tried at my end.

```
df_2 = df_1.groupby(['Period', 'Code'], as_index=False).size()
df_2.head()
```

| Code | Period | size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-04-29 | 2 |
| A | 2022-04-30 | 1 |
| A | 2022-05-01 | 3 |

```
def Cumulative(lists):
    cu_list = []
    length = len(lists)
    cu_list = [sum(lists[0:x:1]) for x in range(0, length+1)]
    return cu_list[1:]

df_2['Count'] = Cumulative(df_2['size'])
df_2.head()
```

| Code | Period | size | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-04-29 | 2 | 2 |
| A | 2022-04-30 | 1 | 3 |
| A | 2022-05-01 | 3 | 6 |

For the row with a `Period` of 2022-05-01, the total count should be 3 instead of 6 because a new month has started.

Comment: so you want a cumulative sum inside months?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on the month (and year to be safe) information from `Period` and apply [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html):

```py
year_col = pd.to_datetime(df_2['Period']).dt.year
month_col = pd.to_datetime(df_2['Period']).dt.month
df_2['count'] = df_2.groupby([year_col, month_col])['size'].cumsum()
```

Result:

```
        Period  Code  size  count
0   2022-04-29     A     2      2
1   2022-04-30     A     1      3
2   2022-05-01     A     3      3
```

Comment: You should probably group on the year as well in case there are rows for a month in two different years

Comment: @Nick: That's a good point. Added.